# How to import export an existing application in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Can we import export an existing application in Oracle Apex?

I mean, one app is there in production but in dev after adding some pages I want to delta export/import.

I have tried to export/import but its replacing new with old as its id already exists.

Comment: You question / intent is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to export/import the **whole** application from *dev* to *prod*; I don't think that there's a "delta" kind of that operation available. It is you who know what the delta is.

If you don't want to do that, as far as I can tell:

- if *dev* and *prod* applications share the same ID (they should)
- they are in a workspace with the same name (they should be)
- perform page-by-page export/import

Answer (score 0):

Apex does not have fine grained change control but there are some tools:

In apex 20.1 you can "export as zip". That will give you a zip file with all the application components as indidvidual files. If you take an export of the app before and after the change, then you can use a version control sytem (like svn or git) to determine what components have changed between 2 versions. Note that this is on component level, so you'll be able to see that Page 2 changed, not the details.

Alternatively, there is a tool available called APEX Diff, written by Martin D'Souza, on https://www.oraopensource.com/blog/?category=APEX+Diff. This tool uses sqlcl to generate a json representation of your application with as only goal to be able to do a diff between 2 applications. I don't know if this tool is up to date with the latest versions.